# Java - Custom rendering Component supporting DnD & Zooming

Tags: java, swing

I want to create a custom Swing component that renders certain enteties and connections between them. The user shall be allowed to select those entities and connections as well as moving them using Drag&Drop (only within that component). Additionally the user shall be able to zoom in and out of the overall view.

*Do you know of any rendering framework that might help creating such a component or do I need to implement it all on my own?*

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A custom rendering program is an item that takes some understood data and turns it into drawing instructions.

If you want to add zooming, your custom rendering program will keep track of the size of the data item it is to draw, and the zoom scaling factor, such that if you were to zoom in 1.1 on a 12 pixel tall item, you would then draw that at 13.2 pixels high.

If you want to add drag and drop, you need to be able to receive a mouse click-and-drag event, which will give you a pixel coordinate.  You back map that starting pixel coordinate to some non-zoomed pixel, then find out the non-zoomed item under that pixel.  You then move that item the (translated for the zoom) correct number of non-zoomed pixels and request a redraw (remember the drawing layer will take care of the current zoom level).

As far as a rendering framework, there are two that come default with Java, and you've mentioned one.  Swing is fine if you really want to build this functionality yourself, and AWT is also in Java, but it probably shouldn't be used independently of Swing unless you have some special requirements.

Outside of that there's SWT, and a number of high level convenience libraries like JGraph, etc which bind to one or other underlying frameworks to do the actual work.  Whether those convenience libraries will do exactly what you wish, or even if they can be configured to do what you wish remains to be seen, depending on the very specific details that will only be discovered and handled after you start trying a convenience library.

Comment: JGraph is a good starting point for building such a component. Thank you!

Comment: @coding.mof Glad to hear it, but some of the requirements might combine in such a way that if the high level convenience library doesn't support it "just so", you wind up having to rip out a lot of code, starting over.  Not saying that will happen with you and JGraph, but it does happen, typically just as you try to finish that last 5%.  Of course, your requirements might be flexible, or perhaps fall directly within what the library makes easy.